# Excel data letters between space how to remove?

Tags: excel, vba

Please look my data first field, my output required second field data format without space in letters

[image: img]

Comment: I would say replace all the spaces with blanks, but it will delete all the spaces even those you need

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Below are some links with tips to get you started. See the **[help/on-topic]** then if, after [*doing more research*](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), you have a *specific* problem, you can [edit] your post to share your **[mcve]** as well as sample(s) of your data and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips [**here**](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [**here**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/) Plus, here's the [**Formatting FAQ**](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell since you posted an image with your example (instead of text within your question) but if I understand, you're trying to remove spaces from text, unless they are next to a comma, so this:

```
A B C D, E F G
```

...becomes:

```
ABCD, EFG
```

---

If that's the goal, then you just need to nest two replace functions.

For example, if the text is in cell `A1` you could...

### Excel:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),",",", ")
```

### VBA:

```
[A1]=Replace(Replace([A1]," ",""),",",", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Aneta pointed out, you could just replace all the spaces with nothing, but then you end up removing spaces that you actually need (eg the ones that separate words).

For instance, 'TEM PL ATE STD TAG.CDL' would end up becoming 'TEMPLATESTDTAG.CDL'.

You could get fancy and use a dictionary to look the words up, but in the case of the word 'TEMPLATE', it could end up being split like this 'TEMP LATE', where both words would be found in a dictionary, making the problem indeterminate.

Another option you have would be to create a dictionary of expected words, remove all the spaces, and then parse each string, looking for matches in your dictionary. Of course, that also becomes unworkable if you have the words 'TEMPLATE', 'TEMP' and 'LATE' in your dictionary since this is once again indeterminate.

Ultimately, unless you have a fixed list of expected csv items, no algorithm in the world is going to know where the spaces really belong!

Comment: hi, LOOKING space remove between letters only